# Making sharepoint site mobile friendly

Tags: sharepoint-online, mobile, mobile-view

I'm trying to make the sharepoint site mobile friendly, but I'm having issues. I don't have access to the master pages or any publishing features so I can't do the device channel option.

If I enable 'mobile view', it redirects the users to a list of folder/files from site content, instead of showing the site. If I switch to 'pc view', it shows the site in its original size, instead of mobile size.

How do I get the site to show as mobile size? I already put CSS modifications for certain width size, but it's not affecting the site on mobile devices.

Answer (score 1):

**"Mobile View"** in SharePoint does not provide a complete mobile view or responsive view of the data presented in "normal mode".

For SharePoint Team Sites the following solution can be implemented:
https://dev.office.com/blogs/announcing-responsive-ui-package-for-sharepoint-on-premises-2013-2016